# Order questions depending on answer votes

Tags: count

I'm really curious about how to create an SQL query to order questions depending the `votes_up` and `votes_down`. (The votes can be the sum of both, `votes_up` + `votes_down`.)

1. Question `has_many` answers
2. Answer `belongs_to` one question

The answer table is like:

```
Answer(id, answer, votes_up, votes_down)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT q.*, SUM(a.votes_up) - SUM(a.votes_down) AS TotalVotes
FROM Questions AS q
JOIN Answers AS a ON a.QuestionID = q.QuestionID
GROUP BY q.QuestionID, q.Question, q.AnyOtherFieldFromThatTable
ORDER BY TotalVotes DESC;
```

I would encourage you to include q.QuestionID (or whatever you call that field) in your GROUP BY clause, for performance reasons.

Comment: So - use the appropriate formula. I wasn't sure whether you wanted the total score, or the total number of votes regardless of whether they were positive or negative. You may want the minus to be plus in the first line.

Comment: Let me notice that your notice on `GROUP BY` applies to MySQL - other RDBMSes should throw an error if `q.QuestionID` (and possibly all other `q` columns) are missing from the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: But you can omit them from the SELECT clause to avoid that particular error. My point is that even if you're not outputting the QuestionID, it's still worth grouping by it.

Comment: hey, @RobFarley.

Thanks for your answer, this is what I was expecting.